# ngPrint in IE10, IE11 browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm using ng print directive for angularjs that provides the ability to print pages built using angularjs.

> https://github.com/gilf/ngPrint

It works in Chrome and Firefox, however in IE browsers, even in the latest ones, the content disappears. There is a line of code where innerHTML is set to "" and then the cloned DOM is appended using appendChild followed by a window.print() function.

```
function d(g) {
            var h = g.cloneNode(true);
            //f.innerHTML = "";
            f.appendChild(h);
            window.print()
        }
```

The page I'm trying to print contains ui-grid tables. On clicking the print buttons, the original contents i'm trying to print shrink in size like shown in the attachment. May be there is some IE quirk that is not adding the css files? How to get around with making it work in IE browsers?

[image: tables collapsed on printing using ng-print in IE]